# time.sleep(0) on Windows vs Unix

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multithreading, sleep

The [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.sleep) states that

> On Windows, if secs is zero, the thread relinquishes the remainder of
> its time slice to any other thread that is ready to run. If there are
> no other threads ready to run, the function returns immediately, and
> the thread continues execution.

but I am confused as to how specifically this is different from the Unix case. When *secs* is zero, does Unix

1. not relinquish remaining time to other threads?
2. not return immediately?

What is a Python example where I could see the difference in behavior?

Edit: this question was closed and associated with [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7273474/behavior-of-pythons-time-sleep0-under-linux-does-it-cause-a-context-switch), which is certainly related. The accepted answer there shows that a context switch occurs when `time.sleep` is called in the Unix case when *secs* **is not zero**. However, it is not clear at all (to me at least) how this answers a comparison of Windows and Unix behavior for the `time.sleep(0)` case, which the Python documentation explicitly says is different.

Edit 2: Pretty sure this went in the duplicate re-opening review queue, but it appears it's off again, with no explanation... This is a little frustrating, as my question here is specific and it's very unclear how the linked answers address it.

Comment: Potentially related: [What is the effect of calling sleep(0) on a UNIX system?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7577643/11082165)

Comment: This is actually a documentation error - it describes the behavior of the [`Sleep`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-sleep) win32 function, when the timeout is 0, however the current implementation uses the [`WaitForSingleObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-waitforsingleobject), which does not describe that similar behavior. However all implementations use a 'system call', so they would trigger a context switch.

Comment: @Brian61354270 Both of those threads (ha) are related and interesting, but I don't think either answers my question. The first seems a bit specific to C++, and the answers do not compare/contrast Unix and Windows. The second is about Python and does show that a context switch occurs in the Unix case, which may be the *start* of an answer to my question.

Comment: A context switch (switching from user-mode to kernel mode) happens in the unix case; however it's not answering your question. There are three potential implementations of sleep on UNIX/Linux - select, nanosleep  & clock_nanosleep. They all have their own behaviors, so  the answer is really *it depends*. clock_nanosleep seems to imply that it will always wait for at least one 'timeslice', but unless you look at the kernel implementation, that's only a spec reading. Relinquishing the timeslice for other threads is only meaningful if you don't have preemptive threading.